# How to set the default editor for a Makefile?

Tags: text-editor, defaults

I want to set the default text editor for Makefiles to something like Atom or Sublime Text to make them easier to open, and so that when I edit remote Makefiles through CyberDuck they will open in one of these editors by default.

Typically, I set a default file type's default 'open' app by right clicking -> Get Info -> Open With -> Change All

However, every time I try to do this for files called 'Makefile', I get the following error:

> An error occurred while changing the application that opens “Makefile”
>   because not enough information is available.
>
> Do you want to open “Makefile” with “Sublime Text.app”?

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this? I am currently on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: It needs a suffix like .txt , .zip, or .myCustomFileType

Comment: Makefiles do not have file extensions. [[Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names)]

Comment: But it needs one to select a standard application...

Comment: @Harcker why?in next step you could set a drive to make an editor open any file.  Macros is basically the same her so what gas that command changed to?